# PowerShell command - what does this output?

Tags: powershell, batch-processing

My colleague found this Batch command (Powershell Command in Windows) online and I need to know what "encoding" it is using to output to the file. I know that it is not utf-8. Here is the command:

```
Select-String logfile.log -pattern "string pattern" | tee-object -filepath "output_file.txt" -append
```

My Windows edition is Windows Server 2012 RC Standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx

> `Tee-Object` uses Unicode encoding when it writes to files. As a result, the output might not be formatted properly in files with a different encoding. To specify the encoding, use the `Out-File` cmdlet.

The command `Select-String` is found in PowerShell.

Comment: Right on, thanks man. I used out-file -encoding UTF8 instead.